# Sync Installed Printers with SQL Server database

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2008, windows-server, printers

Is there any straightforward way to sync installed printers between a windows server and a SQL Server database?

My current thought is to check a database against the data that is generated by `System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters` in a C# application. Getting the ones that are not installed, I would automatically install them either with `ManagementObject` or with `rundll32.exe printui.dll,PrintUIEntry` from a command line. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

This will be running from a Windows Server. Another note, these will be TCP/IP printers.

Comment: My apologies, I am used to referring to MSSQL as simply SQL; the question has been updated accordingly.

Comment: And a lot of other programmers are referring to "just SQL" and mean MySQL by it - or Oracle - or DB2 - it's always better to be clear on what you're talking about.